# TOR will access most links, but some that aren't related to a certain topic

Tags: firefox

I can access most typical sites, such as GoGoDuck, checktorproject, and hiddenwiki, but I attempted(multiple times) to access the BB Compendium, Libera Tor, and other sites having to do with that sort of information, and kept getting a response saying:

"Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at *****.onion
The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few moments. If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's network connection. If your computer or network is protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Tor Browser is permitted to access the Web."

My firewall allows Tor to access the internet, I can access multiple stable sites, and I've been on the aforementioned sites before multiple times

Comment: *DuckDuckGo. But I think I like GoGoDuck better.

Comment: I think the sites you're trying to visit will be down, which isn't unusual for .onion sites, which are often short-lived.